What is the purpose of "DetailedErrors" in the default appsettings.Development.json file for a Blazor Server App?
Using Visual Studio, I created a Blazor Server App with the following default options:

This creates the following appsettings.Development.json file:
{
  "DetailedErrors": true,
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  }
}

I have searched the app for any mentions of a DetailedErrors and the only result is where it is defined in the appsettings.Development.json file.
Can someone explain what "DetailedErrors": true is doing if anything?

It logs detailed error messages to the browser instead of "there was an error"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#detailed-circuit-errors

@BrianParker that is exactly what I was looking for!
